# Offsetting Cells in Sheets with a Condition

Tags: excel, excel-formula, offset, transpose

How would you create a row for every item in "Order" column if the order has an issue that's not "no issue"?

In my example below, I need 1 row for Order A1, 2 rows for H17, and 1 row for J26.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

> =IF(AND(C2 <> "no issue", D2 <> "na", X, Y)

`X` is your action if the `AND` function is `TRUE`
and
`Y` is your action if the `AND` function is `FALSE`

Comment: This won't work for me because I have 20+ issue and comment columns that I need to move to rows if they meet my criteria, which is <> "no issue" and "na". Basically I need to create a row of Order for every valid issue in the Issue column.